# react-leflet map layer repeating

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a map, but it repeats. I would like it to stop repeating, and get only one map. How do I do this?

```
<MapContainer 
    className='h-[700px] w-[700px] float-right mr-10 mt-10'
    center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={5} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
    <TileLayer
      noWrap={true}
      url="/allmap.jpg"
    />
  </MapContainer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you added in the URL a path to image **url="/allmap.jpg"**. as it's an image you can inspect on the **TileLayer** after it's rendered. see on the right side the class which contains this image as **background-image** add to that class the following.

```
.tile-layer-class  { 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

UPDATE:

The problem was that the image was not shown. because there was a style from **leaflet.css** hide the image to show. you can override that style by using the below class.

```
.leaflet-container {
    overflow: unset <= or by using !important as well if that didn't reflect.
}
```

The problem is not related to styling at all. what I figured out that the image is not only rendered just one time in the **dom** but it's gets rendered for **4 images tags.** you can inspect the image and you will see that there're **4 img tags in the dom.**

[image]

I think you will need to find out the reason for why there're 4 images rendered in the dom.
I tried to be honest to do my best. but I'm not familiar with Next.js

Comment: I added this to the `TileLayer` but everything is the same.

Comment: after applying the changes. did you make inspect to check if the styles are reflected in the CSS? maybe they're not reflected because react-leaflet overrides your styles. in this case you will need to add the styles in the global scope for CSS files. or add to them !important.

Comment: I applied the !important, still nothing changed. :(

Comment: can you move them to the global css file

Comment: Yes, I already moved it to the global css file.

Comment: can you share your code on codeSandbox. and add it here.

Comment: It just shows me a blank screen on codeSandbox, but I've imported everything it should require. (btw here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-golick-3rjxil?file=/components/Map.js). Since it is not working I have made a github repository so you can look at the full project.
The map itself is in the Map component, and it's output is in the all.js page.
https://github.com/Jaydendeveloper/gtasaguesser

Comment: @Jaydendev I updated my answer for what I figured out.